# Moving within a designated circle in C#

Tags: c#, drawing

I'm trying to make a simple project in C# but, as I'm kind of new in it, I'm having a lot of troubles. 
What I want to do, is to simulate a movement of a fly within a circle. 
It should work with mouse clicks - first click, you chose the center of a circle. Second click, you chose the radius of the circle and draw it. On the third click (within the circle), you should draw a fly (let's make it a small, filled Ellipse for now) and it should immediately begin to move around.

I've been trying to make this work for more than a week now but without almost any result.

I'm using a panel as the canvas.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 private int start_x = 0;
    private int start_y = 0;
    private int end_x = 0;
    private int end_y = 0;
    private int fly_x = 0;
    private int fly_y = 0;
    private int clicks = 0;
    private int distance = 0;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        clicks++;
        if (clicks == 1)
        {
            start_x = e.X;
            start_y = e.Y;
        }
        else if (clicks == 2)
        {
            end_x = e.X;
            end_y = e.Y;
        }
        else if (clicks == 3)
        {
            fly_x = e.X;
            fly_y = e.Y;
        }
        else if (clicks == 4)
        {

        }
        this.panel1.Refresh();

    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Fly));

        if (clicks == 1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - 2, start_y - 2, 4, 4);
        }
        else if (clicks == 2)
        {
            distance = Distance(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - 2, start_y - 2, 4, 4);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - distance, start_y - distance, distance * 2, distance * 2);             
        }
        else if (clicks == 3)
        {
            t.Start();
        }
        else if (clicks == 4)
        {
            t.Abort();
            clicks = 0;
        }
    }

    private int Distance(int a_x, int a_y, int b_x, int b_y)
    {
        int a, b;
        a = a_x - b_x;
        b = a_y - b_y;

        return (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b)));
    }

    private void Fly()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Graphics e = CreateGraphics();
        distance = Distance(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y);

        while (clicks < 4)
        {             
            e.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - 2, start_y - 2, 4, 4);
            e.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - distance, start_y - distance, distance * 2, distance * 2);
            e.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, fly_x - 3, fly_y - 3, 6, 6);
            fly_x = fly_x - 5 + r.Next(1, 11);
            fly_y = fly_y - 5 + r.Next(1, 11);
            Invalidate();
            if (Distance(start_x, start_y, fly_x, fly_y) > distance - 1)
            {
                if (fly_x < start_x)
                {
                    fly_x = fly_x + 5;
                }
                else
                {
                    fly_x = fly_x - 5;
                }
                if (fly_y < start_y)
                {
                    fly_y = fly_y + 5;
                }
                else
                {
                    fly_y = fly_y - 5;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But, obviously, it doesn't work at all. I can draw the circle, but once i click on the panel again, the circle disappears. Could you point me in the right direction? I mean, what I'm doing wrong?
I tried to do this without using threads and I got so far as to draw even the fly, but at that point, the whole thing froze. 
EDIT:
I deleted the thread and put a timer:

```
 private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        if (clicks == 1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - 2, start_y - 2, 4, 4);
        }
        else if (clicks == 2)
        {
            distance = Distance(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - 2, start_y - 2, 4, 4);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - distance, start_y - distance, distance * 2, distance * 2);             
        }
        else if (clicks == 3)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - 2, start_y - 2, 4, 4);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - distance, start_y - distance, distance * 2, distance * 2);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, fly_x - 3, fly_y - 3, 6, 6);
        }
        else if (clicks == 4)
        {
            clicks = 0;
        }
    }

      private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        fly_x = fly_x - 5 + r.Next(1, 11);
        fly_y = fly_y - 5 + r.Next(1, 11);
        if (Distance(start_x, start_y, fly_x, fly_y) > distance - 1)
        {
            if (fly_x < start_x)
            {
                fly_x = fly_x + 5;
            }
            else
            {
                fly_x = fly_x - 5;
            }
            if (fly_y < start_y)
            {
                fly_y = fly_y + 5;
            }
            else
            {
                fly_y = fly_y - 5;
            }
        }
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }
```

Now it works, but still, the image is flickering a lot, even though I used double buffering. I have a solution from my colleague and somehow, his does not flicker in any way. Is there any other way to correct this than double buffer?

Comment: You don't need a thread you need a timer.

Comment: You can use a timer, or you can just call panel.Invalidate() at the end of your Paint method to ensure that it keeps being redrawn.  I would also recommend that you use a custom control instead of a Panel.  That will allow you to enable the OptimizedDoubleBuffer style in your constructor.  Without it, you'll see some ugly flickering as Windows keeps erasing your drawings with the background color prior to every Paint call.

Comment: I did try to use a timer but it didn't do anything. It is more than possible, however, that I used it incorrectly. Is there anything I should know when using timer?

Comment: Your timer should be calling panel.Invalidate() every tick.  Also, make sure that you've started the timer by setting Enabled = true or by calling the Start() method.  I would recommend a tick interval no larger than 50 milliseconds.

Comment: _just call panel.Invalidate() at the end of your Paint_ No, this will result in a loop&crash|freeze! Use a Timer and set the Intervall (ms) to the speed you want. Also it is good practice to move the Random variable to class level.

Comment: I edited my original post. Is it better?
Oh, yeah, I'll move the random variable.

Comment: A little flicker is really hard to avoid in winforms, which is not really suitable for animation. Did you create a subclass of panel with doublebuffering? (turning it on for the form won't help with the panel!) an alternative to a doublebuffered panel btw is using a picturebox. It also helps to invalidate only the old plus the new area of the fly, not the whole panel..

Comment: _"I have a solution from my colleague and somehow, his does not flicker in any way"_ -- double-buffering is the way to get rid of the flickering. Have you compared your solution with your colleague's solution? It seems like the answer would be there. Have you asked him what he did to avoid the flickering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding flickering in Winforms is not hard, but it does require persistence. Winforms doesn't have any sort of compositing engine — it's a thin layer on top of the unmanaged Windows user32.dll API, and each control in a window is itself a window that is drawn separately — and so each control that could potentially flicker needs to be double-buffered.

Here is a version of your code that does *not* flicker:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Random r = new Random();

    private int start_x = 0;
    private int start_y = 0;
    private int end_x = 0;
    private int end_y = 0;
    private int fly_x = 0;
    private int fly_y = 0;
    private int clicks = 0;
    private int distance = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        label1.Text = "clicks: 0";
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        clicks++;
        if (clicks == 1)
        {
            start_x = e.X;
            start_y = e.Y;
        }
        else if (clicks == 2)
        {
            end_x = e.X;
            end_y = e.Y;
        }
        else if (clicks == 3)
        {
            fly_x = e.X;
            fly_y = e.Y;
            timer1.Start();
        }
        else if (clicks == 4)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            clicks = 0;
        }
        label1.Text = "clicks: " + clicks;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        if (clicks == 1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - 2, start_y - 2, 4, 4);
        }
        else if (clicks == 2)
        {
            distance = Distance(start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - 2, start_y - 2, 4, 4);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - distance, start_y - distance, distance * 2, distance * 2);
        }
        else if (clicks == 3)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - 2, start_y - 2, 4, 4);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, start_x - distance, start_y - distance, distance * 2, distance * 2);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, fly_x - 3, fly_y - 3, 6, 6);
        }
    }

    private int Distance(int a_x, int a_y, int b_x, int b_y)
    {
        int a, b;
        a = a_x - b_x;
        b = a_y - b_y;

        return (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b)));
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fly_x = fly_x + r.Next(-4, 5);
        fly_y = fly_y + r.Next(-4, 5);
        if (Distance(start_x, start_y, fly_x, fly_y) > distance - 1)
        {
            if (fly_x < start_x)
            {
                fly_x = fly_x + 5;
            }
            else
            {
                fly_x = fly_x - 5;
            }
            if (fly_y < start_y)
            {
                fly_y = fly_y + 5;
            }
            else
            {
                fly_y = fly_y - 5;
            }
        }

        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Note that I did not draw into a `Panel` object here, but instead just used the `Form1` object itself. You can accomplish the same basic result applying the same basic technique to a `Panel` or other custom control, but it will mean creating your own `Panel` sub-class (or a regular custom control, inheriting `Control`) and putting all of the above code into that instead of in the form. I.e. you'll still use `override` on the `OnMouseDown()` and `OnPaint()` methods instead of attaching event handlers; you can still use the Designer to drag-and-drop a `Timer` object onto your custom class.

The key is that the control into which the drawing is actually being done, needs to have its `DoubleBuffered` property set to `true` (it's `false` by default). Since the property is not `public`, the right way to do this is to subclass the type and set it in the constructor (you could use reflection on a plain `Panel` object, but that's ugly and non-obvious). In the above, the `Form1` class is already a sub-class I have control over, so it's easier to set the property there, than to create a new custom control for the purpose.

A couple of other points about the code:

- You might want to consider using the `MouseClick` event instead of `MouseDown` for the mouse interaction. This behaves in a way that's likely more what the user would expect; the two major differences are, the event happens on mouse-up instead of mouse-down, and it doesn't happen at all if the user drags away from the control before releasing the mouse button (i.e. offers the user a way to change their mind and avoid the click).
- I noticed that your random-walk had what seemed to me to be a bug in it. You were generating values between -4 and +5, which of course causes the "fly" to work its way to the lower-right corner of the circle. I changed your randomization code so that it generates values from -4 to 4 instead, giving an even distribution in all directions. I fixed this in the above code example by just providing the correct values to the `Next()` method overload, and removing the unneeded `- 5` from the computation
- Most importantly, your randomization code had a serious-but-common-bug in it: you created a new `Random` object every time you wanted a new value. This produces **non-random** results, due to the fact that by default the random-number-generator is seeded with the system clock. In the worst case, the code is selecting values so quickly that each new `Random` object is initialized identically, and so returns the same value; even in the best case, where the code delays between random values, the returned values are still correlated with the clock, rather than being a true random distribution. I fixed this in the above code example by moving the `Random` object to a private field with an initializer, so that a good random sequence of values is generated (technically, "pseudo-random").

Comment: FYI: PictureBox is a simple way to get a Control with DoubleBuffering on by default. I would also use the Invalidate(Rectangle) overload when only a tiny bug is moving around ;-)

Comment: @TaW: it is, but IMHO that's a lot of extra "weight" (maybe not run-time, but at least conceptually) to carry around just to set a flag. You are right that invalidating just the changed area is more efficient; however, in my experience it is difficult for people learning an event-driven rendering model to correctly determine the rectangle to invalidate. IMHO, that's better as an "intermediate" topic, though granted here the drawing case is so simple it probably wouldn't distract much from the main point.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Duniho . This was an amazingly detailed answer and, even though I'm mostly a beginner, I still understood most of it.